# Blank Image getting created

Tags: java, imagej

```
import ij.*;
import ij.gui.GenericDialog;
import ij.gui.NewImage;
import ij.plugin.FolderOpener;
import ij.plugin.filter.PlugInFilter;
import static ij.plugin.filter.PlugInFilter.DOES_8G;
import static ij.plugin.filter.PlugInFilter.STACK_REQUIRED;
import ij.process.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

 * Calculates the average values of pixels located at the same
 * position in each slice of the stack and adds a slice showing the average values to the end of the stack.

public class Recon_2d implements PlugInFilter {
    protected ImagePlus imp;
    int Bin_number, Bin_size;
    int[] average ;
    public int setup(String arg, ImagePlus imp) {
        this.imp = imp;
        return DOES_8G+STACK_REQUIRED;
    }
    public void run(ImageProcessor ip) {
        GenericDialog gd0 = new GenericDialog("Parameters");
        gd0.addNumericField("Bin_Number", Bin_number,0);
        gd0.addNumericField("Bin_Size", Bin_size,0);
        gd0.showDialog();
        if (gd0.wasCanceled())  return ;
        Bin_number = (int)gd0.getNextNumber();
        Bin_size = (int)gd0.getNextNumber();
        ImageStack stack = imp.getStack();
        int[] sum;
        int[] [] recon = null;
// takes pixels of one slice
        byte[] pixels;
        int dimension = ip.getWidth()*ip.getHeight()*Bin_number;
        sum = new int[dimension];
        int width=ip.getWidth();
        int height=stack.getSize();
        int l=0;
        for (int i=1;i<=stack.getSize();i++) {
            pixels = (byte[]) stack.getPixels(i);
// add the value of each pixel and the corresponding position of the sum array
            for (int j=0;j<stack.getWidth();j++) {
                for (int k=0;k<Bin_number;k++){
                    for( l=0;l<Bin_size;l++){
                        sum[l]+=0xff & pixels[l];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        average  =new int[dimension];
// divide each entry by the number of pixels in each bin
        for ( l=0;l<dimension;l++) {
            average[l] = (byte) ((sum[l]/Bin_size) & 0xff);
        }
        try{ 
            int [][] PixelArray=new int[width][height];
            BufferedImage bufferImage2=new BufferedImage(width, height,BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
            for(int b=0;b<Bin_number;b++){
                for(int y=0;y<height;y++){
                    for(int x=0;x<width;x++){
                        int Pixel=PixelArray[x][y]<<16 | PixelArray[x][y] << 8 | PixelArray[x][y];
                        bufferImage2.setRGB(x, y, PixelArray[x][y]);
                    }
                }
                File outputfile = new File("D:\\Output\\new"+b+".jpg");
                ImageIO.write(bufferImage2, "jpg", outputfile);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ee){
            ee.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to create `Bin_number` number of 2D images of size `width*height` of gray scale. But blank images are getting created. Initially I will have `height` number of images of size `width*l`. I have to redimension this stack of size `width*l*height` to stack of 2D images of size `width*height*bin_number`, where `bin_number` is User Input. `Bin_size` is also User Input. For example, if width=1024,l=1024, height or input stack size, in other words input images are say 100 of size `1024*1024`, then 8 bins of bin_size 128 can be obtained in which case the number of output 2D images will be 8. So 2D output images will be 128 of size `1024*100`.

Comment: Please pick a language

Comment: you want to create which type of image... BMP-1,2,4,8,16,24,31,64 -bit....
and do specify the language please...

Comment: Sorry, 8 bit gray scale, Java on ImageJ tool.

Comment: Actually I want it in .tiff but its not working, so as of now I am creating in .jpg format.